# How can i have distinct selection from a list on the basis of id?

Tags: c#, linq

I have folowing list that but i want distinct rows on the basis of catID how can i achieve this?

```
lst.AddRange(
            (from xx in this.FreeInstructionItems
             select new selectedCustomization()
             {
                 TypeName = CategoryType.SpecialInstruction,
                 CategoryName = xx.InstructionInfo.CatName,
                 ItemName = xx.InstructionInfo.Description,
                 SourceID = xx.InstructionInfo.InstructionId,
                 CatID = xx.InstructionInfo.CatID,
                 Items = GetAllFreeItemNames(CategoryType.SpecialInstruction, xx.InstructionInfo.CatID)
             }
            ).ToList()
            );
return lst;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy` using `CatID` property and return `First` element of every group:

```
return lst.GroupBy(x => x.CatID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

[MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and DistinctBy is better than all the GroupBy hacks:

```
return lst.DistinctBy(x => x.CatID);
```

Comment: sounds interesting, have you experienced `MoreLinq` enough? Is it reliable?

Comment: It's written by Jon Skeet. Need I say any more?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var results = 
    (from xx in this.FreeInstructionItems
     group xx by xx.InstructionInfo.CatID into g
     let instrInfo = g.First().InstructionInfo
     select new selectedCustomization()
     {
         TypeName = CategoryType.SpecialInstruction,
         CategoryName = instrInfo.CatName,
         ItemName = instrInfo.Description,
         SourceID = instrInfo.InstructionId,
         CatID = instrInfo.CatID,
         Items = GetAllFreeItemNames(
             CategoryType.SpecialInstruction, 
             instrInfo.CatID)
     });
lst.AddRange(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst.AddRange(this.FreeInstructionItems.GroupBy(x=>x.InstructionInfo.CatID)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()
                                      .SelectMany(x=> new selectedCustomization()
              {
               TypeName = CategoryType.SpecialInstruction,
               CategoryName = x.InstructionInfo.CatName,
               ItemName = x.InstructionInfo.Description,
               SourceID = x.InstructionInfo.InstructionId,
               CatID = x.InstructionInfo.CatID,
               Items = GetAllFreeItemNames(CategoryType.SpecialInstruction, xx.InstructionInfo.CatID)
              }).ToList());
```